# Fetching data from API failed

Tags: reactjs

I am testing out the fetch API in React but it doesn't display anything and keeps loading... I'm not sure where i did wrong. Did the server just fail to send data back?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
    import './App.css';

    const API_30 = 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {campers: []};
        }
      componentDidMount() {
        fetch(API_30)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({ campers: data.campers })
          );

      }

      render() {
    if(!this.state.campers){return <p>Loading...</p>}
        return (
         <div className="App">
            <h1 className="Table-header">FreeCodeCamp Leaderboard</h1>
           {this.state.campers.map((camper) => 
             <div>{camper.username}</div>
           )

           }

              </div>);
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: provide us with what showed in the network section of browser

Comment: it just displays "Loading..." on the browser.

Comment: only if data.campers is undefined, will you see the loader since `!this.state.campers` will return false initially since this.state.campers is set to true. check your API response to see if data.campers is undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch(API_30)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ campers: data })
      );
```

It is not `data.campers` it was just `data`.

You can see the data that is returned from the api by `console.log`ing the data.

if you do

```
fetch(API_30)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data)
      );
```

you can see in the console that the data is already an array.